# Microsoft OneDrive resource owner password flow

Tags: c#, winforms, api, oauth-2.0, onedrive

I'm trying to get a winforms app to implement a connection to Onedrive, but from what i have seen it's not possible to have a flow where the user doesn't have to see a form and type in their username and password. Not having to type in the username and password is part of our business rules.

Has anyone had any luck or found any great examples of this to reference, as I have not. Also i'm sure this isn't the best place to post this since it's more of a discussion. So if you'd like to direct me to where I should post it that would be fine as well, then I can repost it.

Comment: Hi Marsh, can you tell me more about what you’re trying to accomplish that wouldn’t be allowed to have user authentication. Is that because the user doesn’t have a onedrive account (you want to use a service account) or because you want a single sign-on experience for existing users?

Comment: We want to use it in the place of a database for files that a user would upload. The users are part of an organization, and the organization would be the owner of the OneDrive account. So what we're thinking is that the user won't have to know the user/password to upload or pull files, it's just something happening in the background.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm)
OneDrive only supports

- Token Flow (Implicit grant)
- Code Flow  (Authorisation code grant).

You could implement code to auto-populate credentials into the identity provider's HTML login form and POST back to the identity provider (I've seen that done in automated testing tools) but then you have to handle situations like scope granting dialogues or even password changes so would not recommend trying this.